# Java annotations and method conformance

Tags: java, annotations

I have a newly defined annotation that is targeted at methods. Is there a way to annotate it in such a way that when I apply it to a method a() of class A, it will also apply to a method b() of class B which inherits from A, provided that b() conforms to a() in some way- similar names, conforming input types, conforming return types, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "no". Annotation only applies to the explicitly annotated target (method / field / class). If annotation itself is annotated with `@Inherited` it will also apply to descendants of annotated target; but that won't help with your case (if I understood correctly).

However, depending on what you intend to use that annotation for, you can either write your own [Annotation Processor](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html) to do whatever you want or simply use reflection to look up appropriate method and decide whether your annotation should **logically** apply to it as well.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm able to determine, there isn't a way to mark an annotation is inherited for anything other than classes (via @Inherited).